# C# Sort Coordinate Points ascending

Tags: c#, arraylist

I was given this C# code to generate 10 random coordinate points. The code generates an ArrayList with the 10 coordinates, prints the objects, sorts them, and prints them again:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace Point
{
    class Program
    {

        public class Point
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;

            public Point(int X, int Y)
            {
                x = X;
                y = Y;
            }
            
            override public string ToString()
            {
                return y + "." + x;
            }
            
        }

        public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myList)
        {
            foreach (Object obj in myList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
  
            ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();
            Random R = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i< 10; i ++)
            {
                Point p = new Point(R.Next(50), R.Next(50));
                AL.Add(p);
            }
            PrintValues(AL);
            AL.Sort();
            PrintValues(AL);

        }
    }
}
```

To my questions:

1. Why is the `ToString()` method in the class Point automatically called even if I dont use `p.ToString()`?
2. How is it possible to compare the Points in this case? Do i need to change the type to int or double?

Comment: ArrayList only still exists for backwards compatibility to code from before generics where introduced with .Net 2 way back in 2005, for the old project settings lists visual studio, and compatibility with PowerShell collections. Do not use ArrayList outside of those very specific scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #1, look at the [documentation for `Console.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_). There are several overloads, but the one matching the way you call the function expects a string and an object. That overload knows to use the `ToString()` method on the passed object. You could simplify the line even further like this, which will do the same thing:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

If you had not provided a `ToString()` method with the `Point` class, it would have used the one inherited from the base `Object` type, which by default will print the type name.

---

For question #2, we again [look to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/comparisons-and-sorts-within-collections). The link I provided describes the process .Net will use to find a suitable **Comparer** instance that can be used to sort the items in the collection.

Note if you follow this documentation closely, and the documentation for [`ArrayList.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.sort?view=net-5.0) on through to the appropriate [`Array.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_) overloads, we see there is no suitable comparer available, *which should cause this code to fail*. I suspect somehow a default comparer is inferred, possibly for the `string` result from the `ToString()` overload.

---

Hopefully you spotted a theme in this answer, and that is *read the documentation.* Even long-time C# users like myself need to refer back to in constantly.

Finally, I might write that code like this to use a generic list and `Point` type already included in the .Net.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Point
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myList)
        {
            foreach (Object obj in myList)
                Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static Random R = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            var points = new List<Point>();
            for(int i = 0; i< 10; i ++)
            {
                poinst.Add( new Point(R.Next(50), R.Next(50)));
            }

            PrintValues(points);
            PrintValues(points.OrderBy(p => p.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. I also tried to use the documentation but couldnt find the right path for it. Your linked helped me.